# Wer ruft wen? Pronomen und Demonstrativpronomen zwecks Unterscheidung zweier Substantive

Tags: sentence-structure, pronoun

> Die Kinder versprachen ihren Eltern, sie jeden Tag anzurufen, worauf
>   diese tatsächlich jeden Tag anriefen, was ihnen aber bald lästig war.

oder:

> Die Kinder versprachen ihren Eltern, sie jeden Tag anzurufen, worauf
>   sie tatsächlich jeden Tag anriefen, was diesen aber bald lästig war.

Wer ruft hier jeweils wen an, und wem sind die Anrufe lästig?

Gibt es einen Konsens über folgende Faustregel, an die ich mich normalerweise halte:

> Das Subjekt des Satzes wird in Nebensätzen durch normale Pronomina
>   vertreten, ein danach auftretendes Substantiv durch ein
>   Demonstrativpronomen.

Offenbar muss das noch präzisiert werden. In beiden Beispielsätzen gibt es zwei relevante Substantive: die Kinder und die Eltern (der Tag zählt in diesem Zusammenhang nicht). Die Frage ist: Wie nehme ich auf die einen, wie auf die anderen Bezug? Und die These: "sie" bezieht sich im ganzen Satz auf die Kinder. Will ich auf die Eltern Bezug nehmen, muss ich ein anderes Pronomen verwenden, und zwar das Demonstrativpronomen "diese". Wird dies konsequent gemacht, gibt es keine Verwechslung (in diesem Fall wäre also der zweite Satz richtig). Man könnte natürlich auch das Paar "diese" und "jene" verwenden, das wäre aber in meinen Augen ein Overkill, außerdem kommt es in der Praxis viel weniger häufig vor als "sie" und "diese", die dann leider oft verwechselt werden. Meistens kann man als Leser den Fehler aus dem Kontext korrigieren, aber im ersten Beispielsatz eben nicht.

Ist dieser Grundsatz Allgemeingut, findet er Anklang, ist er irgendwo festgelegt?

Comment: Der erste Satz ist für mich durch das "diese" extrem verwirrend. Das "diese" impliziert einen Rollenwechsel (hier von Objekt zu Subjekt), der aber garnicht stattfindet. Die Kinder sind die ganze Zeit in der Agens_Rolle. "Die Eltern baten ihre Kinder sie anzurufen, worauf diese das auch taten". Hier liegt ein Rollentausch vor und hier finde ich das "diese" angebracht. Das "diese" im zweiten Satz sollte besser "jene" sein, da in der direkten Kontrastierung "diese" die Kinder sind und "jene" die Eltern.

Comment: Aber davon abgesehen verstehe ich die Faustregel nicht genau. Was heißt "danach". Wann ist dieses "danach". Versteh ich das richtig, dass es dir im Grunde darum geht, wann "sie", "diese" und "jene" benutzt wird?

Comment: @Emanuel Das "diese" impliziert einen Rollenwechsel. Genau das habe ich gemeint und wollte ich bestätigt haben. Der erste Satz war in diesem Fall absichtlich "falsch", aber leider findet man dafür häufig Beispiele in Texten aus Zeitungen etc.

Comment: Schon das "worauf" ist schlecht, denn es kündigt eine Reaktion an. Im ersten Teil agieren aber die Kinder, die Reaktion kann daher nicht auch ihre sein.

Answer (score 3):

In beiden Beispielen ist klar, dass die Kinder täglich anrufen, denn es waren die Kinder, die es versprochen hatten. In diesem konkreten Fall ist es also egal, ob man *diese* oder *sie* schreibt. Hier obsiegt die Bedeutung über der Grammatik (die in beiden Fällen korrekt ist).

Anders ist es im Fall von **was *ihnen/diesen* aber bald lästig war**: Das Pronomen an dieser Stelle könnte sich sowohl auf die Kinder als auch auf die Eltern beziehen. Das ist zwar auch beim Pronomen aus dem ersten Teilsatz der Fall, aber anders als dort gibt hier die Semantik nicht vor auf wen sich das Pronomen beziehen soll.

> ... was ihnen aber bald lästig war.

Hier tendiere ich dazu zu verstehen es wären die Kinder, denen die Ausübung der täglichen Pflichtübung lästig ist.

> ... was diesen aber bald lästig war.

Mein erster Gedanke war, dass es in diesem Fall den Eltern lästig ist täglich angerufen zu werden. Aber je länger ich darüber nachdenke, desto weniger sicher bin ich mir ob damit tatsächlich die Eltern gemeint sind. Es könnten auch die Kinder sein.

Der Satz ist - egal mit welchem Pronomen - mehrdeutig. Solche Fälle kommen häufig vor. Am einfachsten ist es, die Pronomen durch Umschreibungen zu ersetzen (z.B. *die Jungen* bzw. *die Alten*), oder den Satz komplett umzuschreiben.

Comment: Totally agree. Im zweiten Teil ("diese") ist es tatsächlich so, dass beide gemeint sein können. "Ihnen" ist dagegen eindeutig die Kinder.

Comment: Das heißt, ihr seid der Meinung, "diese" allein reicht nicht als Verweis auf die Eltern?